# Finding entities with same attribute with MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, entity-relationship, magicalrecord

I can do it for current value

```
NSArray *entities = [WallpostEntity findByAttribute:@"text" withValue:someText andOrderBy:@"pubDate" ascending:NO];
```

How can I do with all same values?
For example I want array of entities with entities that have  same "text" value

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you aren't finding the attribute that has inverse relationship